# Como paginar um array Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

Existe alguma maneira *simples* de paginar um Array em Laravel?

Eu tenho um array *$atendimentos* que data uma pesquisa faz o retorno do tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até a versão 5 existia o método

```
Paginator::make($atendimentos, count($atendimentos), 10);
```

No qual passava o array, o tamanho dele e o numero de registro que você queria por pagina. Entretanto ela foi retirada e pesquisei muito, mas não encontrei nada nas nova versões.

Editado: Eu estou usando no sistema ***LengthAwarePaginator*** no resto do sistema e imagino necessário neste caso também, pois meu array de $atendimentos vem de uma pesquisa. Porém se houver alguma maneira com o ***Paginator*** aceito sugestões.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator tem sim

Comment: @novic reaberto, fique a vontade para formalizar uma resposta, apesar de acreditar que a pergunta precisa de esclarecimentos, pois tem casos que terá que ser  `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` e outros `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na [documentação](http://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) do Laravel, ainda `Paginator` como mencionado na sua pergunta, no caso da edição foi especificado `LengthAwarePaginator`, então crie uma instância seguindo todo o `namespace` que é descrito na documentação:

Ressalvas:

- 1 - a variável `$atendimentos` só deve vir o total de itens que serão apresentados na sua `View` (pode ter filtros e ordenação);
- 2 - a variável `$atendimentosTotal` é a quantidade geral de registros (pode ter ou não filtros e está bem relacionado ao item 1, só que difere porque aqui é o total de registro e no item 1 é a parte que vai ser apresentado geralmente demonstrado pela pagina atual do item 4);
- 3 - a variável `$atendimentosTotalPorPagina` é o `count($atendimentos)` e;
- 4 - a variável $pagina é o número da página atual.

---

Código:

```
$page = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
    $atendimentos, 
    $atendimentosTotal, 
    $atendimentosTotalPorPagina
    $pagina
);
```

Como é manual tem que calcular essa variáveis antes de passar nesse classe para que ela organize todas as informações e te apresenta corretamente os dados.

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [LengthAwarePaginator](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html)
- [Pagination](https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pagination/)

Comment: Tem como exemplificar a sua variavel atendimentos? tem como colocar na pergunta?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-slice.php @PauloMartins

Comment: @PauloMartins porque você não faz direto na `builder` do seu Eloquent?